# Applying XML coloration style on TextMergeViewer Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, plugins

I recently found this guy's website, claiming he had found a way to set XML syntax coloration in a TextMergeViewer, a thing that is not "naturally possible" in Eclipse.

Here is the URL of his website : https://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/merge-compare-dialogs-and-xml-syntax-highlighting/

However, the way he dealt with the issue seems to be not applicable right now (in 2016, and I am running Eclipse 4.4.0). The two major problems I found are the following ones :

- StructuredTextViewer cannot be resolved as a type (I see many forums telling that we cannot/could not access it)
- It looks impossible to cast a StructuredTextViewerConfigurationXML to a SourceViewerConfiguration.

I am not pretending that he is a liar, but I guess that I missed something, or Eclipse performed some internal changes affecting his code, written in 2010.

If someone knows how to solve these issues, his help would be welcomed.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StructuredTextEditor` and related classes are part of the Eclipse Web Tools. In particular the 'Eclipse XML Editors and Tools' feature.

Some downloads of Eclipse include this, other don't. If you don't have it you can install it using 'Install New Software...'. Choose you main Eclipse site and look for 'Eclipse XML Editors and Tools' in the 'Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development' section.

Comment: Could you give me further information about something, please : I installed, as you told me to, the 'Eclipse XML Editors and Tools'  tool, and everything is working fine on my computer. Unfortunately, my mates are not able to download my plugin from the update site because of some missing dependencies. The error message refers to "org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.902". For me, it looks like what I installed.  How could I provide it packed with my plug-in ?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: They either have to install the same set of tools or you need to build a 'feature' plugin that includes all the required extra plugins and then use 'Export > plug-in development > deployable features'

Comment: I'll have a  look to the second option. I need to avoid the first one because the main idea is to keep it as simple as possible for the end-user.